# Memory is not getting released

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, memory-management, memory-leaks, nsmutablearray

When I run the following program ... application is holding some 5MB of memory even after releasing all objects ... when I don't add an object to list everything works fine ... but I am not sure why application is holding memory even after releasing the list.

I have read this link "[NSMutableArray big memory hog](http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/29905-nsmutablearray-big-memory-hog.html)?" and even tried with custom mutable array by mikeash [MACollections](https://github.com/mikeash/MACollections) -- in all the cases ... the memory allocated in the loop never get released if I add the object into list.

Please advice me some suggestion to know what is going wrong in the code flow. I appreciate your valuable time and help.

```
@interface TestData : NSObject 
{
    NSString *strData;
}
@property (nonatomic,retain)NSString* strData;

@end

@implementation TestData

@synthesize strData;

- (void)dealloc
{
    self.strData = nil;
    [super dealloc];
}

@end

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

    NSMutableArray *list = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    TestData *_object = nil;
    NSString *val = nil;
    for (long i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
    {
        _object = [[TestData alloc] init];
        val = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%lu",_object];
        _object.strData = val;
        [val release];

        [list addObject:_object];
        [_object release];
    }

    [list release];


    [pool release];

    return NSApplicationMain(argc, (const char **)argv);
}
```

Update:
I used "vmmap" command in terminal ... I can see some thing like this ...

```
                                     VIRTUAL   RESIDENT      DIRTY ALLOCATION      BYTES MALLOC ZONE                             SIZE     SIZE       SIZE      COUNT  ALLOCATED  % FULL
===========                          =======  =========  =========  =========  =========  ======

DefaultMallocZone_0x100005000          37.0M      5868K      2692K     8548      1210K      3% 
DispatchContinuations_0x1000cc000      4096K   48K        48K          1         32      0% 

unnamed_zone_0x100037000  0K         0K         0K          0         0K

===========                          =======  =========  =========  =========  =========  ====== 
TOTAL                                  41.0M      5916K      2740K       8549      1210K      2%
```

so looks like though the object is released ... it is still app memory as unused space ... not sure what can be done in this case. I am not sure is it a fragmentation issue ... or behavior.

Comment: In `TestData`s `dealloc`, I wouldn't use `self.value = nil;`, it's not safe to use `self.` when the object is deallocing. Instead, use `[value release]`

Comment: How are you calculating that 5MB of memory is still being held after release? This is quite old style code, is there a reason you don't want to use ARC?

Comment: @WDUK I am referring memory used by app in Activity monitor.

Comment: Few days back I answered similar kind of problem, where release was not working as it should be... check this link..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13737571/memory-management-of-objective-c-2-0/13737691#13737691

Comment: I suspect there's nothing wrong.  I've never used that tool, but I think it's just reporting the unused but still allocated heap -- the "high water mark" reached during execution.  Running Analyzer is the best way to smoke out storage bugs.

Comment: This seems odd: `val = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%lu",_object];`.  You will print the decimal representation of the object address.  Is this what you intended?

Comment: I just intender to create different string objects ....